# Square tube or C-channel for gate frame

Tags: metal, gates, welding

I will built a frame for a wood gate like the one below (but mine will slide in a track instead of hang on hinges).

[image: Wood gate with metal frame]

I was thinking on using C-channel instead of tubing for the frame, since it will make it easier to screw the planks to the frame and the screws will be semi-hidden. Also, the c-channel is thicker per weight, so easier to weld with stick eletrodes.

I never saw a gate frame using C-channel, are there any problems using it for that? Apart from the looks on the inside, will tubing provide any real advantage (considering similar weight materials)?

Comment: I'm no expert, but if it is the same strength, as long as it is stainless steel (or properly painted) you should be fine!

Answer (score 1):

Square tube (or I-beam) is a trifle stronger than C-channel/C-beam. You may not need that additional strength, depending on exactly what you're building. C-channel is a bit lighter, which may not matter for your application.

(I'm using square-tube aluminum for the bike trailer I'm modifying. C-channel would probably have been fine for this application, but the weight and price differences were insignificant so I went for overkill.)

Answer (score 0):

The major advantage of c-channel is that you can actually paint all of the surfaces so rust is manageable. With tubular, you can't protect the inside from rust and corrosion. I would use c-channel for that reason alone.

Comment: I understand that (I failed to mention it though in my post). I was (am) a bit worried about using it because I actually never saw a gate using c-channel. I think it might be because of the looks of it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You'll want the slot pointing downwards as not to collect water